# Is there a tool for sending a daily digest from a set of SVN repositories?

Tags: svn, agile

My team has a range of projects spanning several SVN repositories.  Along with the daily updates from meetings and emails, I would like a daily digest email that summarises the commits from the set of repositories that we're using.  I've seen similar things within project management tools like Unfuddle, but wondered if there was a simple utility out there that did just this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a widget out there that does this or not.  But I would think that if you stood up (or perhaps already have) a continuous integration environment (I use CruiseControl and NAnt) then you could aggregate all of the reports generated in a day across all of your repositories from a single CruiseControl project and build file that runs at the end of the day.  This project would be reponsible for picking up the various reports/logs from the other build and including them into a build email...  Sounds like that would work.

Perhaps there is something more elegant out there!  I can't wait to see the other responses.

Answer (score 1):

(On windows) you could install [CommitMonitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor). You can configure any number of SVN repositories to be watched/monitored at configurable intervals. The tool shows you all new commits and allows you to check each commit in details.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at http://devpulse.com/ (disclaimer: I am part of the team behind it). At the moment it doesn't exactly have a daily digest, but it let's you have RSS/Twitter stream of all events/changes in your repositories (and other tools).

Answer (score 0):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

"It provides an interface to  Subversion (or other version control systems), an integrated Wiki and convenient reporting facilities."

Comment: I've looked at trac, but I don't think it easily handles multiple projects that well (correct me if I'm wrong).  It's great for a single project of course.  It's also a much larger utility than what I'm looking for (we already have bug-tracking and a wiki).

Comment: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects

Comment: sourceforge.net uses Trac and I'm pretty sure they have more projects than you ever will. ;)